Proving $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$ for profinite groups
Let $G$ be profinite group and $H\subseteq K$ closed subgroups. We want to prove the statement in the title. Now for any open normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ we have
$$
[G/N:K/K\cap N]=[G/N:H/H\cap N][H/H\cap N:K/K\cap N]
$$
Now, Ramakrishnan and Valenza claim that we can compute the lcm of the product on right by computing lcm of each factor. To prove this they say since choosing a smaller open normal subgroup would inflate both factors, this is possible. I don't understand this argument and appreciate any help.
